# .NET Web Services without ASP.NET/IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm implementing a server component that needs to expose a web-service interface, but there is no application need for it to run with ASP.NET on IIS. Is there a straightforward way to implement Web Services in .NET without ASP.NET/IIS? (I'm using .NET 3.5 / C# 3.0)

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: @dcw Just curious as to why you want to avoid IIS 7 as a WCF host?  Thanks!

Comment: @dcw sorry...I didn't mean to add the '7' in my comment.  I'm just curious as to why you would choose to avoid IIS in general. thx!

Comment: Zach: There's no profound insight. I simply need to be able to use port 80 to drive various server processes, but don't want to oblige my client to have IIS on all machines. HTH. :-)

Comment: There are many reasons to avoid IIS. For instance if you want to create a stand alone server application or simply because you think you can do something better than IIS. Why most .NET developers are so stuck with the Microsoft Guru vision?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class to host a service. The [WCF tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935.aspx) contains sample code.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're using a verson of .Net that supports it, you should be looking at the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).  You'll need SOME process to host these services, so if you don't use IIS, you may end up writing your own EXE to host the service, but that's where you should start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663309.aspx

Answer (score 5):

[Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)

This is an older article but still relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Yes use [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If you use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) (Windows Communication Foundation), which has pretty much superceded Web Services, you can host in a Windows Service or in IIS.