# Is it Possible to consume WCF service (which is hosted as Windows Service Hosting) through httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, service

I have to create a windows service for reading some machines data for the customer client application. But, I dont have option to host the service in IIS. Customer can only consume the service through web url using webrequest. 
Is there any possibility to consume the WCF service hosted in windows service using webrequest.

Hosting method should not be in IIS and consuming the service should be a type of webrequest (I dont have any idea on this).
client will only call net.tcp,http URL types to consume the service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tha answer here might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485061/net-web-services-without-asp-net-iis  ... It will be possible to consume a WCF service via a HttpWebRequest, But it might be a little fiddly to get the XML data in the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for your response @sam. The discussion on the provided link is about hosting a service without IIS. I'm aware of hosting wcf service as windows service and self hosting but for consuming these two types client application needs references of service. But in my case Client can only consume the service through URL. (Cannot add service reference dlls to client) Client is SAP.

Comment: Ah, Yeah - Well, ServiceHost will let you spin up a little HTTP server without IIS. Consuming the XML WCF service via HTTP is then a matter of getting the XML in the right shape -- You don't need the service references that you would usually add in Visual Studio, These just help you to create the XML requests easily, but it's quite possible to create them yourself and use a plain old HTTP request, It's just a bit more work.

Comment: @sam Can you please provide some links for the sample codes or projects, Thanks.

Comment: As you know, wcf is able to create the restful style service, which depends on Http protocol. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
it could be consumed by the Http request with different Http verb, which could be created by the HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah - WCF services are just SOAP services so it's quite possible to call them with any decent HTTP client.

I'd suggest you use a tool like Postman to debug your service, which should make this pretty clear - This blog post is about just that: https://code.firozansari.com/2017/10/21/making-wcf-service-request-using-postman/

You can also have a look at these examples that demonstrate calling a WCF SOAP service using simple HTTP clients in other languages:

http://mkonrad.blogspot.com/2013/02/call-custom-wcf-soap-service-from.html

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-REST-WCF-Service-SVC-using-WebClient-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx